# webrtc simple capture and adding image overlay

Tags: webrtc

My goal is to create a simple snapshot with webrtc with adding some simple image overlay on `<video>` element

Then save this to jpeg

I tried with

```
<canvas id="canvas">
<video  id="video"></video>
</canvas>
```

But video is not diplayed then.

I would like to have all that in a simple canvas, so I would just need to use

```
window.location=canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
```

To save to jpeg

Any clue ?

Comment: Do you set your video to play? May want to set it to `autoplay` in your video source element

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using a `<video>` element inside a canvas, but you can use `.drawImage` to put the video contents on the canvas.

```
function raf(){
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame();
}
```

Wheareas `video` refers to the video element. After this you can draw your overlay on the canvas (remember to put this in te animationframe, else it gets overwritten by the video), and then call `.toDataURL('image/jpg')` to get your image.